# I, a 14-year-old, prayed to Jesus as God. Can this act of Shirk be forgiven?

Tags: shirk, prophet-isa, christianity, forgiveness

At age 14, I thought that Shirk was simply believing in more than one God. I then thought foolishly that Christianity might be true, and so I prayed to Jesus Christ (PBUH) as God. I feel sick to my stomach thinking that I have committed Shirk. I realized my mistake not too long after the prayer. Can I be forgiven if I repent?

Comment: Under Christianity, Jesus is willing to hear the prayers of sinners who trust in him. Even if someone “repents” from him as if from Shirk, he is still willing to accept that person back and forgive them.

Answer (score 1):

### ﷽

The answer by brother Ten is good. Sincere repentance is necessary for the forgiveness of ANY sin. Turn to Allah (swt) and never return to any shirk.

*In Surah Az-Zumar 39:53, it has been revealed,*

> *Say, ˹O Prophet, that Allah says,˺ “O My servants who have exceeded the limits against their souls! Do not lose hope in Allah’s mercy, for Allah certainly forgives all sins. He is indeed the All-Forgiving, Most Merciful.*

Allah (swt) has no limits. No sin is greater than His mercy. He is Merciful.

*On the authority of Anas (may Allah be pleased with him) (Related by at-Tirmidhi, also by Ahmad ibn Hanbal), **the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was heard saying,***

> *Allah the Almighty said: O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind. O son of Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you. O son of Adam, were you to come to Me with sins nearly as great as the earth and were you then to face Me, ascribing no partner to Me, I would bring you forgiveness nearly as great as it.*

Trust in Allah's mercy. Thinking Allah cannot forgive you is wrong, but this does not mean you should commit shirk again because, surely, you will be damned for good. Ignorance can no longer be an excuse now that you have been informed of the grievousness of shirk.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

> "Allah forgives not that partners should be set up with Him, but He forgives anything else, to whom He pleases, to set up partners with Allah is to devise a sin most heinous indeed" (Quran An-Nisa 4:48).

You need to do some reevaluating with you life, especially islamically. What you did was no doubt foolish and terms like these cannot be played around with, even as a joke. Imagine if you died that second “as a joke” you prayed to Jesus Christ. You would’ve died as a non Muslim, banished to hell.

Were you aware of Shirk being a non forgivable sin? Because like the verse listed above, Allah forgives all sins except Shirk. Since you for a moment in time had doubts about Islam and prayed to Jesus, I think you should retake your Shahada, and reevaluate your life. Study Islam better so you can prevent foolishness like this from occurring again. Despite being 14 years old doesn’t make you clearly exempt from doing like this. You’re not young anymore. In the eyes of Islam you’re an adult.

> 1. Say, “He is God, the One.
>    2. God, the Absolute.
>    3. He begets not, nor was He begotten.
>    4. And there is nothing comparable to Him.”
>    (Quran Al-Ikhlas, 1-4)

Allah says in the Quran, Surah Furqan:

> And the ones who do not invoke another god (along) with Allah, nor kill the self that Allah has prohibited except with the truth nor commit adultery; (i.e., illegal sexual intercourse) and whoever performs that will meet the penalty for vice. their torment will be doubled on the Day of Resurrection, and they will remain in torment, disgraced, Except him who repents, and believes, and does righteous deed(s). So those, Allah will turn (Or: substitue fair deeds in place of odious ones) their odious (deeds) into fair (deeds); and Allah has been Ever-Forgiving, Ever-Merciful. People who repent and do good deeds truly return to God).
> 68-71

Repentance from shirk means giving it up and submitting to Allaah alone, regretting one's neglect of Allaah’s rights and resolving never to go back to it. Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> Say to those who have disbelieved, if they cease (from disbelief),
> their past will be forgiven
> Quran Al-Anfaal 8:38

Refer to: [Repenting from Shirk](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/20482)

Long story short, repent, repent, REPENT sincerely, and NEVER play games like that again. Shirk isn’t like any ordinary sin; it stands out. You can’t play it off like any ordinary sin by falling into it again and then going back to repent. You’re either Muslim or not. Study Islam better if you have doubts, clear your misconceptions. I’d also advice you to retake your shahada and reevaluate your beliefs, because for that moment, when you had acted like a Christian, you had denounced the Prophethood of Muhammad (SAWS).

May Allah guide us all to the straight path and keep us firmly on it. Ameen.